# using uuid and bcrypt with django not generating unique values

Tags: python, django, uuid

building a uuid then hashing it with bcrypt ends up generating an object with the same value in auth_secret(uuid4() is not generating a unique value for each new instance) every time one is initialized. Here is the terminal output

```
>>> from quickstart.models import FarmUserAuthentication
>>> c = FarmUserAuthentication('as')
>>> d = FarmUserAuthentication('asdfs')
>>> c
<FarmUserAuthentication:  $2a$12$euUMcvhPwPsS7SQgiOVGNeWr792cq.tKONl9bTVjY3nvrxpczPqs6>
>>> d
<FarmUserAuthentication:  $2a$12$euUMcvhPwPsS7SQgiOVGNeWr792cq.tKONl9bTVjY3nvrxpczPqs6>
```

here is my code in models.py

```
class FarmUserAuthentication(models.Model):
    auth_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 10)
    hash = bcrypt.hashpw(str(uuid.UUID4()), bcrypt.gensalt())
    auth_secret = models.CharField(max_length=100, default= hash, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a fundamental error in Python, I believe, by trying to structure your class as you've seen in Django models.

This:

```
class FarmUserAuthentication(models.Model):
    # ...
    hash = bcrypt.hashpw(str(uuid.UUID4()), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

[is a class variable, not an instance variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). Thus, the value is shared between all instances of the class.

If you want a unique value for each instance, the normal way to do this would be in the `__init__` function. However, [in Django you should not override `__init__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects), so you should simply add a function to your model that creates your hash. Perhaps something like this:

```
class FarmUserAuthentication(models.Model):
    def get_hash():
        return bcrypt.hashpw(str(uuid.UUID4()), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Or because you can't call things easily in Django templates, perhaps a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class FarmUserAuthentication(models.Model):
    @property
    def hash():
        return bcrypt.hashpw(str(uuid.UUID4()), bcrypt.gensalt())
```